# Seeding orders for Spree getting Inventory units is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I’m trying to seed orders for my store to test the system, but getting

> *** StateMachines::InvalidTransition Exception: Cannot transition state via :next from :address (Reason(s): Inventory units is invalid,
>   Inventory units is invalid)

I checked and the `InventoryUnits` that are invalid is missing `shipment_id`, but couldn't figure out what is causing it. Not all InventoryUnits for an order is missing the `shipment_id`, only a couple. I couldn't find the file where the code that instantiates the `InventoryUnits` for an order, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

**What could cause the `shipment_id` to be `nil` and which file contains the code that created the `InventoryUnits` (so that I can try and figure that out).**

You can find my seed code [here](https://gist.github.com/harinsa/a9472b2f68e827f91efe).